# Can response files of Oracle software installation be unified with the others?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, installation

Can I have the content from the response file that creates a DB instance and a listener clubbed into the content of the response file that silently installs just the Oracle software?
How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put them all in the same response file. But the installation response file has `oracle_db_install_LaunchDBCA` and `oracle_install_LaunchNetCA` flags, and you can specify the `oracle_install_db_dbcaCmd` and `oracle_install_netcaCmd` paths. I'm not sure if you can add flags to those commands in situ - I've never thought to try - but you could change them to scripts that launch `dbca`/`netca` with the silent and response file flags.

They will be separate processes but they'll be launched from the main software installation, so you'll only have to run one command - that seems to be what you're asking for. Alternatively you could wrap the three silent command (installer, `dbca` and `netca` with appropriate flags) in a script and just run that.